# Memory quota exceeded using Wordpress on Shared Azure Website

Tags: wordpress, memory, azure

I'm trying to wrap my head around a memory quota violation. In the wild, if I have a vm and I try to run something beyond its memory limits (SSMS, for instance, on my VPS), SSMS simply crashes and says "not enough memory, dude."

Apparently on Microsoft Azure, if you request a function that takes you beyond your allocated memory... IT TURNS YOUR SITE OFF FOR AN HOUR.

I can't explain how awful that is, and from the other similar questions I've seen about Azure memory quotas, most of you can't either. BUT...

Is there anyone out here with Wordpress experience on Azure who knows how to keep memory usage down? Alternatively, is there anyone here with Wordpress experience on any platform who can explain what kinds of activities might draw more than 512Meg at a time?

Any help would be good help.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that you will not get a satisfying answer to your question. In very few cases will the run-time memory characteristics of websites with server-side code be predictable enough to ensure that you do not hit the quotas and for production scenarios many people will go with basic/standard instead of free/shared. Have you seen [Scott Hanselman's article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudWhenDoAzureWebsitesMakeSense.aspx) on the feasibility of Azure Websites?

Comment: had the same issue.anu news?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question because as the first responder said -- there isn't a satisfactory answer. I ended up going with a different hosting company that offers dedicated WP hosting, and have had no issues whatsoever.

I love MS. I use their technology stack whenever feasible, but sometimes you gotta call a spade a spade: I am not sold on Azure yet, though not for lack of trying.